# Casting to base class in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Why does the copy constructor get called when I cast a derived object to the base class in C++ ?

```
Derived d;
std::cout << (Base)d;
```

Comment: You can't change the type of an object at runtime. Therefore, casting must produce a new object.

Comment: So the copy constructor of Base is called with d as an argument...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082453/object-oriented-programming-inheritance-copy-constructors

Comment: When does the destructor of Base get called to destroy the new Base object?

Comment: `(Base)d` creates a temporary `Base` object that lives until the end of the statement where it's declared. The destructor will automatically fire once the statement ends.